# splitting a CSV and keeping the header without intermediate files

Tags: bash, curl, cat, tail, csv

I am trying to split a dozen 100MB+ csv files into managable smaller files for a curl post.

I have managed to do it but with a lot of temporary files and IO. It's taking an eternity.

I am hoping someone can show me a way to do this much more effectively; preferably with little to no disk IO

```shell
#!/bin/sh

for csv in $(ls *.csv); do
    tail -n +2 $csv | split -a 5 -l - $RANDOM.split.
done

# chose a file randomly to fetch the header from   

header=$(ls *.csv |sort -R |tail -1 | cut -d',' -f1)

mkdir split

for x in $(/usr/bin/find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.split.*'); do
    echo Processing $x
    cat header $x >> split/$x
    rm -f $x
done
```

The above script may not entirely work. I basically got it working through a combination of these commands.

I decided to make the curl POST another step entirely in the case of upload failure; I didn't want to lose the data if it were all posted. But, if, say, on error from curl the data could be put into a redo folder then that can work.

```shell
#!/bin/sh

# working on a progress indicator as a percentage. Never finished.
count=$(ls -1 | wc -l 2> /dev/null | cut -d' ' -f1)

for file in $(/usr/bin/find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
    echo Processing $file
    curl -XPOST --data-binary @$file -H "Content-Type: text/cms+csv" $1
done
```

Comment: This question has been cross-posted at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708081/splitting-a-csv-and-keeping-the-header-without-intermediate-files

Comment: this really looks like an XYProblem:  what do you need to do? are you sure you need to do it via multiple http post? if you have access to the machine, you can scp, rsync, etc.

Comment: `$(ls *.csv)` is redundant; just use `for csv in *.csv`.

Comment: @OlivierDulac -- I actually have to POST it because it has to be processed by a webservice. It's not just a straight upload.

Answer (score 4):

An entirely different approach would be to use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), and use its `--header` and `--pipe` options:

```
cat input.csv | parallel --header : --pipe -N 10 'cat > output{#}.csv'
```

This will get you 11 lines in each of the files (the header line plus the ten from `-n 10`, except in the last file written that way).

Comment: This looks interesting. I will have to give this a try.